# Invalid mapping pattern detected: /**/swagger-ui/**

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springdoc-openapi-ui

I am using springdoc-openapi-ui for spring boot API documentation and facing the following issue -

[image: This is the error screen]

I have added all the necessary configuration as follows -

1. The maven dependency -

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

2. This is the main file -

```
package com.abc.tl;
    
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.OpenAPIDefinition;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
@OpenAPIDefinition
public class TLApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(TLApplication.class, args);

    }
}
```

Using java version - 11, Not sure where is the Issue, the project is not able to run.

Comment: Have you tried to specify swagger path directly through properties file: `springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-ui.html`

Comment: @VadimB - yes I have tried that also but no luck

Answer (score 13):

I added below line in my app application.properties that worked for me.

```
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy = ANT_PATH_MATCHER
```

Answer (score 12):

With following dependencies, solved this issue.

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It failed the build for me due o Relying upon circular references is discouraged and they are prohibited by default. Is it a good Idea to allow circular dependency?

Answer (score 4):

The above item works
`spring.mvc.pathpattern.matching-strategy=ant_path_matcher`

However, it should be `ant-path-matcher` - dashes not underscores

Answer (score 2):

Seems The `PathPatternParser` doesn't allow `**` to appear in the middle, and will reject such a pattern (see more details: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/21694).

It looks like code here inserted a `**` in the middle of the path pattern.

```
    uiRootPath.append(ALL_PATTERN);
    registry.addResourceHandler(uiRootPath + SWAGGER_UI_PATTERN)
```

Full code

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    StringBuilder uiRootPath = new StringBuilder();
    if (swaggerPath.contains(DEFAULT_PATH_SEPARATOR))
        uiRootPath.append(swaggerPath, 0, swaggerPath.lastIndexOf(DEFAULT_PATH_SEPARATOR));
    if (actuatorProvider.isPresent() && actuatorProvider.get().isUseManagementPort())
        uiRootPath.append(actuatorProvider.get().getBasePath());

    uiRootPath.append(ALL_PATTERN);
    registry.addResourceHandler(uiRootPath + SWAGGER_UI_PATTERN)
            .addResourceLocations(CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATION + DEFAULT_WEB_JARS_PREFIX_URL + DEFAULT_PATH_SEPARATOR)
            .resourceChain(false)
            .addTransformer(swaggerIndexTransformer);
}
```

Comment: Where do I need to to add this code ?

Comment: @BabitaBisht see how u config your web config file

Comment: I am new to spring boot, where will I find this web config file ?

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your code (I would guess in the security configuration) you have configured `/**/swagger-ui/**`. Recently (Spring 5.3) these path configurations are now analyzed by `PathPatternParser` (that replaced the old `AntPathMatcher` that allowed paths just like these).

Either add `spring.mvc.pathpattern.matching-strategy=ant_path_matcher` to your `application.properties` as suggested or change the your path configuration to something like `"/webjars/swagger-ui/**"`.

Comment: I tried adding spring.mvc.pathpattern.matching-strategy=ant_path_matcher but it did not work

Comment: Have you tried the second approach? Changing your path configuration to something like `"/webjars/swagger-ui/**"`.

Comment: The second approach worked for me. (I updated from Spring Boot 2.5 to 2.7. Since 2.6 the PathPatternParser is the default.) Try this property instead: ``spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant-path-matcher``

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was using old versions of `springdoc-openapi-ui` `springdoc-openapi-data-rest`, which happened to be incompatible with the latest version of Spring Boot. Looking up for the most recent maven package on https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springdoc/springdoc-openapi-ui and using that version, solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I added this line my side is working application.properties

```
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy = ANT_PATH_MATCHER
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case springdoc-openapi-ui was in outstanding module. And I just exclude springdoc-openapi-ui.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>some.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>some.artifact</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
                <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```