# Spring Boot : Invalid mapping pattern detected: /**/swagger-ui/** How to resolve it

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

How to resole it ?

Description:

> Invalid mapping pattern detected: /**/swagger-ui/** ^ No more pattern
> data allowed after {*...} or ** pattern element

Action:

> Fix this pattern in your application or switch to the legacy parser
> implementation with
> 'spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant_path_matcher'.

Comment: You can search on the site. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69283400/invalid-mapping-pattern-detected-swagger-ui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have spring boot starter parent 2.6.2 and springdoc-openapi-ui dependency version 1.6.3 in my pom.xml

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And I can see swagger UI on my machine at http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html