# Invalid mapping pattern detected: /**/swagger-ui/** : Is there any solution to this issue?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

When I upgrade my Spring Boot API to 2.6.1 version, I am getting this error.
URL ant matcher in my API likes: `/v1/token/**`.

Any solution for this error:

```
Invalid mapping pattern detected: /**/swagger-ui/**
^
No more pattern data allowed after {*...} or ** pattern element

Action:

Fix this pattern in your application or switch to the legacy parser 
implementation with 'spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant_path_matcher'.
```

I already added the `spring.mvc.pathpattern.matching-strategy=ant_path_matcher` to `application.properties` file, but it not works.

Comment: Can you post your configuration to see more details.
Though basically you can not use an all matching wildcard `**` followed by a hardcdoed literal and another wildcard.

Comment: This is My configuration :  webSecurity.ignoring().antMatchers("/token/**", "/v1/token/**", "/v2/token/**", "/v2/authenticate/**", "/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/swagger-ui/index.html");

Comment: I cant find the matcher from the provided error. Can you post the stacktrace as well? And add your configuration to your answer please. In case the stacktrace tells you a line of code, please include them too.

Comment: this is due to [spring 5.3.x upgrade](https://spring.io/blog/2020/06/30/url-matching-with-pathpattern-in-spring-mvc)... solutions: or set that property, or find(, please!) this wildcards, and replace them (with something better suited). [non-resolved-duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69283400/592355)

Comment: ..springfox or springdoc??

Comment: private static final RequestMatcher PROTECTED_URLS = new OrRequestMatcher(
            new AntPathRequestMatcher("/v2/**") // TODO: Only securing /v2 endpoints for second round, once ready should secure all endpoints with /**
    );
    AuthenticationProvider provider;
    @Override
    public void configure(final WebSecurity webSecurity) {
        webSecurity.ignoring().antMatchers("/token/**", "/v1/token/**", "/v2/token/**", "/v2/authenticate/**", "/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/swagger-ui/index.html");
    }

Comment: [one more (duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70405474/592355), yesterday

Comment: @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(provider)
                .addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(PROTECTED_URLS)

Comment: nono, i assume *not in your sources* but somehwere in (swagger-ui related) dependencies

Comment: .authenticated()
                .and()
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .logout().disable()
        ;
    }
  }

Comment: (you can edit the post...) https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/776

Answer (score 0):

spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy = ANT_PATH_MATCHER  add this in application.properties for me its working

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).